# Label data based on prior records in spark

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, java-8

I am working on incorporating Spark and MySQL for data processing in Java for a small exercise to determine repetition in criminal behavior. I have been able to set up everything okay, but am banging my head against a wall in order to get the following logic to work.

Given a table of the following information  - I want to be able to label the following, with the  instance of how often that item has occurred. This is calculated when the person is doing their community service:

- NO HISTORY : if the person has no prior criminal history; instance count of zero
- GOOD HISTORY : if the person had no fight history and has done community service in the last 90 days; instance count of comm service in last 90 days
- FIGHT HISTORY : if the person has atleast one fight in their history; instance count of fights

Given :

| incident_date | person_involved | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | Ronny G. | FIGHT |
| 2020-02-03 | Ronny G. | FIGHT |
| 2020-02-10 | Stella B. | COM SERVE |
| 2020-02-14 | Ronny G. | COM SERVE |
| 2020-03-15 | Stella B. | COM SERVE |
| 2020-05-01 | Stella B. | COM SERVE |
| 2020-10-01 | Stella B. | COM SERVE |

Expected:

[image: expectedtable]